# fails gazebo to start from ROS (boost::exception_detail error)

Tags: gazebo, roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I am working on ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTE Thrusty (OK, I know it is not yet released).

When I try to start Gazebo, it fails most of the time (1 time in 10, it works). I use the simple command:

```
$ roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

Here are the messages:

```
$ roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
... logging to /home/arnaud/.ros/log/251a3d96-e35b-11e3-9539-0016eae586be/roslaunch-hercules-11967.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://hercules:46195/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: <...>
 * /rosversion: <...>
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [11979]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 251a3d96-e35b-11e3-9539-0016eae586be
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11992]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [12016]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver: 5: [: Linux: unexpected operator
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [12020]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient: 5: [: Linux: unexpected operator
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for masterError [Connection.cc:787] Getting remote endpoint failed
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  remote_endpoint: Transport endpoint is not connected
[ INFO] [1400946636.551182005]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
Msg Waiting for master
[ INFO] [1400946636.557603492]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.1.211
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 12020, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/arnaud/.ros/log/251a3d96-e35b-11e3-9539-0016eae586be/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/arnaud/.ros/log/251a3d96-e35b-11e3-9539-0016eae586be/gazebo_gui-3*.log
[ INFO] [1400946637.091142150, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1400946637.167613885, 0.093000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
^C[gazebo-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

This one fails either:

```
roscore & rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

The only way I found to make it work is to start one by one, roscore, gzserver and gzclient.

Does it come from the unstable state of ROS Indigo? Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168856/fails-gazebo-to-start-from-ros-(boost::exception_detail-error)/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2014-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2014-05-26**:
Any ideas are welcome. Do you think that it could come from my hardware? (LENOVO T400)

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2014-05-27**:
I have found the same issue on the Gazebo forum: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6271/getting-remote-endpoint-failed-let-gazebo-gui/

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2014-05-28**:
Finally posted an issue in GitHub: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/421

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-09-11**:
I experience same issue, running ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04. roscore & rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo does not work, produces the following error: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc
Yet, I am able to start gazebo using roscore, gzserver, and gzclient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was resolved here: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/196

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0